# Text7 PDF Manipulating: Page X of Y - Error Trailer not found

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm using iText7 creating PDF documents in memory. Lately I was trying to add Page X of Y but I get the error: 'Trailer not found.'. I read tons of pages of documentation of @Bruno and Stackoverflow but I couldn't find the same situation like mine.
All the examples that I found are dealing with manipulation of a PDF file on disk and not with a dynamically created in memory like mine.

Now I'm stuck with the Error "Trailer not found".

Any help is apreciated.

```
Using stream As New MemoryStream
    Using Writer As New PdfWriter(stream)
        Using PdfDoc As New PdfDocument(Writer)
            Using doc As New Document(PdfDoc)
                Dim tbl As New Table(1)

                '# this creates a table splitted on 3 pages
                For i = 1 To 99
                    tbl.AddCell(New Cell().Add(New Paragraph(i.ToString + " - sample content added")))
                Next

                '# adding the table to the document
                doc.Add(tbl)

                '# resetting the position in the memorystream
                stream.Flush()
                stream.Position = 0

                '# this line throws an exception: iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Trailer not found.'
                Using pdfOut As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(stream), New PdfWriter(Server.MapPath("~/test.pdf")))
                    Using docOut = New Document(pdfOut)

                        Dim tp As Integer = pdfOut.GetNumberOfPages

                        For np = 1 To tp
                            docOut.ShowTextAligned(New Paragraph(String.Format("page %s of %s", np, tp)), 559, 806, np, TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0)
                        Next

                    End Using
                    pdfOut.Close()
                End Using
                PdfDoc.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

After having tried out more combinations I found it out myself.

Closing the Document, after having written all the content, and trasforming the memorystream to a Byte() array did the trick.

```
doc.Add(tbl)
doc.close()
 '# now this line doesn't throw any exception'
  Using pdfOut As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(stream.ToArray), New ...
... more stuff here
```